# Не показывает информацию о диске C

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    string DiskName = string.Format("Название диска - {0}", drive.Name);
    string DiskType = string.Format("Тип диска - {0}", drive.DriveType);

    if (drive.IsReady) // Проверяем готов ли диск
    {
        string DiskM = string.Format("Метка диска - {0}", drive.VolumeLabel);

        string TypeFSystem = string.Format("Тип файловой системы - {0}", drive.DriveFormat);

        string DiskClearMb = string.Format("Общее доступное место - {0} мб", GetSizeInMegabytes(drive.TotalSize));
        string DiskAllClearMb = string.Format("Всё свободное место - {0} мб", GetSizeInMegabytes(drive.TotalFreeSpace)); GetSizeInMegabytes(drive.AvailableFreeSpace);
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                myWriter.WriteLine(DiskName + "\n" + DiskType + "\n" + DiskM + "\n" + TypeFSystem + "\n" + DiskClearMb + "\n" + DiskAllClearMb + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
}


long GetSizeInMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return bytes / 1024 / 1024;
}
```

Должен показывать инфу о всех дисках, а показывает только о диске D. Почему?

Comment: `new StreamWriter(path)` - каждый раз создает _новый_ файл, затирая предыдущее содержимое.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вот блин, слона-то и не заметил =( Может ответом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта строка: `new StreamWriter(path)` - каждый раз создает новый файл, затирая предыдущее содержимое. В итоге в файле оказывается информация о самом последнем диске.

Я бы переписал код следующим образом:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drive.IsReady)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Название диска - {0}", drive.Name);
            writer.WriteLine("Тип диска - {0}", drive.DriveType);
            writer.WriteLine("Метка диска - {0}", drive.VolumeLabel);
            writer.WriteLine("Тип файловой системы - {0}", drive.DriveFormat);
            writer.WriteLine("Общее доступное место - {0} мб", GetSizeInMegabytes(drive.TotalSize));
            writer.WriteLine("Всё свободное место - {0} мб", GetSizeInMegabytes(drive.TotalFreeSpace));
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Пишем сразу в поток. Метод `WriteLine` имеет перегрузку, принимающую строку формата.

Промежуточные переменные не нужны. Хотя можно их оставить - иногда они улучшают читаемость и упрощают понимание кода.

Обработка исключений - по вкусу.